# Why wouldn't the Kree Empire condemn Ronan's actions?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Irani Rael pleads with the Kree to take action against Ronan. Why wasn't the Kree ambassador willing to at least condemn Ronan's actions?

> "Ronan is destroying Xandarian outposts throughout the galaxy. I should think that should call for some slight response on the part of the Kree?"
>
> "We signed your peace treaty, Nova Prime. What more do you want?"
>
> "At least a statement from the Kree Empire saying that they condemn his actions. He is slaughtering children, families."
>
> "That is your business. Now I have other matters to attend to."

The tone of his response seems suspicious. Do the Kree secretly support Ronan's mission despite the treaty with Xandar? Or was he just annoyed at another request from Nova Prime?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that in the comics, the Kree are militaristic and blood thirsty, having been at war with the Skrull for hundreds of thousands of years. I think the implication was that the Kree don't care if Ronan is planning to wipe out the Xandarians, as they reluctantly signed the peace treaty and as such have nothing to do with it. Of course, this may be something dealt with in the sequel.

Comment: Out-of-universe, I'm pretty sure somebody just wanted to treat us all to Glenn Close saying "Prick!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR: The Kree are arrogant & typically take the attitude "If it doesn't affect us, it doesn't matter."**

In Marvel's main (Earth-616) continuity, the [**Kree**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Kree) are an aggressive, militaristic race who have been defined largely by their millenia-old war against the [Skrull](http://marvel.wikia.com/Skrulls). In pursuit of victory against the Skrull, the Kree have committed all manner of atrocity, including the total devastation of entire planets & solar systems. Any respect they have for others such as [The Nova Corps](http://marvel.wikia.com/Nova_Corps_(Earth-616)) is a respect of strength, not of compassion.

[image]

Within the MCU, much of the [Kree](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Kree) remains the same. They are still an arrogant, aggressive race known for their advanced techology & military might. Despite their peace treaty with the [**Nova Empire**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Nova_Empire), it is quite likely that many Kree privately agree with Ronan's disdain for their former enemies. Even those who do not most likely have total apathy towards the plight of the Xandarians, or in fact ANY other race besides the Kree.

So, essentially, the Kree ambassador's response perfectly sums up the Kree attitude.

Comment: So, basically, it's because they're all twats. :)